# Call private fields by passing Function in java8

Tags: java, java-8

Help me with problem at the comment, please. I'm newbie with java8. It would be great too if you give me some keyword for searching.

```
public class aClass{
    public Function<String,String> f;
    private void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("done");
    }
    public void addF(Function<String,String> f){
        this.f = f;
    }
}

public class bClass{
    public String func(String str){
        System.out.println(str);
        //Call doSomething();
        //Can I do that? 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        aClass a = new aClass();
        a.addF(this::func);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you need /trying to achieve?

Comment: Hint: you are talking about methods, not fields. And no, the essence of the private keyword is to restrict visibility to the scope of the enclosing class.

Comment: And then read about Java naming conventions. Class names start UpperCase - always.

Comment: I want to nest doSomething() into f(), but f() is defined external so I can not solve. Do you have any idea? Sorry about my English. I'm so bad at English.

Comment: No, Its not my question. As you can see, f() was declare inside aClass and define code in bClass

Comment: You can write a method in `aClass` that first calls `f.apply()` and then calls `doSomething()`. Is that what you need? P.S., you are passing a bad method reference to `a.addF()`.

Comment: @Eran Thanks for support. I got it now.